# find index of any character from list in string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am interested in finding the character index from a string, where the character is either space or _ (underscore) or - (hyphen).

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ','kjhk wonderful', 1)
```

(Returns 5)
can be used if I search for 'space', but I am interested in either one of the symbols mentioned, that comes first. Any ideas please? What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[ _-]%','kjhk wonderful')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's messy, so there may well be a neater way, but the following will work.

```
SELECT MIN(pos) FROM
(
    SELECT CHARINDEX(' ','kj-hk won_derful', 1) AS pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CHARINDEX('_','kj-hk won_derful', 1) AS pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CHARINDEX('-','kj-hk won_derful', 1) AS pos
) as query
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188395.aspx):

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[ _-]%', 'kjhk wonderful')
```